# while showing a div it's always showing at top of page

Tags: jquery, css

i have a div with fallowing css style..

```
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #C3CFD1;
display: block;
height: 480px;
left: 262px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 44px;
width: 517px;
z-index: 2000;
```

i am showing this div on click of button which is lower down in my page..the problem is..when i am opening this div it's getting open but always at the top of page..but what i want is, it should always get open relative to page that is if i am at lower site of my page it should get open there only not at top....solution in jquery will also beappriciated..

Any help or suggestion will be heartily appreciated...!!!
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: play with position, left , top css values http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: yes i did this but not happening for me.:(

Comment: use position: relative; remove margin-left and margin-right if you use left: proprety , or better stop using left and top and use margins

Comment: i did...but then div went down at the bottom of page..

Comment: in you're html place the div beneth you're button , then position:relative should display it beneth you're button , then all you have to do is make small adjustments to left and top .

Comment: @Vivek - Are you *sure* the styling in the question is indeed getting applied? It should work, unless it's not being applied or *another* `position` is being used, by a more specific selector.

Comment: @Nick yes style is being applied to div!!  it's showing me in firebug under element.style...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't, by any chance, be testing in Internet Explorer and be in Quirks mode? I made a quick test and it works in other browsers, but not IE. When I changed from Quirks to Standard mode, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/eH6pS/ . By now, I'm guessing that you were missing the `return false;` The tests I did were without jQuery and using `href='javascript:toggle()'` attribute (not good practice, but enough for a CSS test).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `position: fixed;` to `position: relative;`
The value 'fixed' stucks the element at a specific place at all times, where 'relative' works like z-index and will be the top layer at all times.

Comment: while i am changing it to position: relative; it's getting open at bottom of page..

Comment: `position: relative` puts the element relatively to it's position in normal flow. Not what Vivek needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want something like that, but you would need to bind it on a scroll event

```
$('#tester').css('top',$('body').scrollTop() + 'px');
```