# why is .show() making the target div appear at top of page?

Tags: jquery, css

I am having a similar issue to this user [while showing a div it's always showing at top of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561259/while-showing-a-div-its-always-showing-at-top-of-page).

I am trying to get a div to show in the proper place, but currently when I click the active link for .show(), the div is appearing, but it appears at the top of the page overlapping everything.

Here is my .js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".hiddenreviewform").hide();
        $('.exposeform').click(function() {
                $(".hiddenreviewform").show();
                return false;   

        });
    });
```

And here is the CSS for the hidden div:

```
.hiddenreviewform{
    height: 486px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 556px;
    margin-left:244px;       
}
```

What is very odd to me, is that if I remove the js and remove display:none on the hidden div, it appears in exactly the right spot when i refresh the page.  Yet if I hide the div and then show it using jquery, it appears at the top of the page.  I've tried adding position: relative to the hidden div and this did not remedy the issue.

This is exactly how my code appears, and for whatever reason it works in codepen but not on my local machine.
http://codepen.io/donnaloia/pen/raxjbb

the only difference is that that entire codepen example is nested inside more parent divs (I was unable to copy and paste the rest, because the css is minified and i wasn't sure how to copy and paste the relevant code from that file).  So am I to assume that the way the parent divs are setup is affecting the positioning of my hidden div on show() ?

Any answers or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you inspected the element in your browser to determine that no unexpected CSS is being applied?

Comment: I can't even click the link because of the negative margins. I'd try to create your layout without them.

Comment: I just inspected and I see element.style { position: absolute }  Is that what's causing this?  I think that is overriding the position:relative that I set to that div.

Comment: Yea my CSS is extremely messy, I am going off of a ZURB foundation css template, and there is stuff going on that I don't understand, the only way I am seemingly able to position things is with negative margins, and now this issue.

Comment: Yeah, absolute positioning could cause trouble. Not necessarily, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some recommendations for you.

1. **Some of the `<div>` tags inside `<div class="hiddenreviewform">` is not closed properly.**
2. Don't use this much`<br>` tags. It is not good practice. Use `margin`, `padding` etc to position your data properly.
3. Your `styles` are really (sorry to say) messy. Do some work on them first.
4. And for ratings use `☆` (symbols i.e. `& #9734;` without space ) rather than images.[This](http://character-code.com/special-character-html-codes.php) site will be handy.

**First point will get your job done.**